# Python: logging from multiple files

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to implement logging for the first time, but having a problem.
I have a setup where I am calling other files from within a file. I am trying to log into a file from every point.

For some reason the called file does not log anything, because when I open log file ('snake.log'), all I see is:

```
2015-09-01 14:55:40,598 - test_logging - INFO - Program started
2015-09-01 14:55:40,598 - test_logging - INFO - Done!
```

my code is here:

```
#main.py
--------
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import sys
import os
import logging

def main():

    logger = logging.getLogger("test_logging")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    fh = logging.FileHandler("snake.log")
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info("Program started")

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 

    # list of scripts to be executed
    metric_scripts = [
                       'file_1.py'
                      #,'file_2.py'
                      #,'file_3.py'
                     ]

    index_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y.%m.%d")

    for script_name in metric_scripts:
        run_path = script_dir + '/' + script_name
        cmd = "python " + run_path + " " + index_date
        os.system(cmd)

    logger.info("Done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



#file_1.py
-------------
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("test_logging")
logger.info("Pulling data ...")

def main():

  process_date = str(sys.argv[1])

  print "Doing someting here ..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Don't say "calling a file", say "running a script". Also, why are you calling other python scripts instead of importing?

Comment: Can I run it as: file_1.main() ? Could you post an example, please?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `os.system` is going to run your script in another processes, and the logging module does not have a way to communicate across processes to consolidate your logging information. The logging for file_1.py will be written to that process's stdout. And as far as I can tell, os.system does not make the process output available after the call, so you will not be able to view or output those log lines.